# How Should I handle the data on local and cloud in an react native app (Redux)

Tags: react-native, redux

I have an app and its going to have these features in it :

**SCREENS** :

**Home** { Show recent posts from all categories (API provides 30 posts per page)}

**Categories** {Show all Categories List }

**By-Category** {Show recent posts by category (API provides 30 posts per page)}

**Post** {Show Post Details with Comments }

**User-Profile** {Show User Profile with their recent posts (API provides 30 posts per page)}

**Profile-Setting** {Show updatable Fields and Update Button}

Now, Where i am confused :

1. Should I fill the whole store with API in the starting or should I
   make API calls for each screen when they are opened ?
2. And for updating, like If user likes post then should I show a
   spinner or something till API completes OR should I update the local
   store value instantly and then call the API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many approaches to solve this. mine is:

1) I would create a model/manager to handle the API requests that also have access to the same store. so for example when the screen did mount use Home.Manager.getNextPage(); and it will know already to handle the api request and also know how to handle the paging.

So all the calcs will be in the manager. and when it get the data it will update the store with it.

2) When I built an app that contained likes I have used local data as well. My approach was to set time out of 10 seconds from last like so in case the user liked more than one post I could send a bulk. so the server won't need to handle multiple tcp connection but one with multiple likes data.

The point was first store it locally(for incase the user kill the app before we update the server) and then wait for 10 s' if got new like add it to the data array and wait for another 10 s' if not just send the data to the server. do not clean this local data until server return that it saved on your db

This way you can display animation first without letting the user to wait for a feedback from the server..

Comment: If i am getting you right, If user kills the app then On next startup i should update the db ? And if yes, then should i have one more store to keep track of the changes ?

Comment: yes, but you don't need track of changes. when app is starting up you should check if you have anything saved locally to update the server. and update it on the background if there is.
The pros of this way is that you can send bulk of updates with one request. you could also just update each click but this could be bad for the server. (make sure to check on the background that the request is completed!)

Comment: You could also use a broker like rabbitMQ . or build one on your own. this will be a mid server that just keep all user tasks/msgs and it makes sure the main server get's it. and if it don't or busy it will try again later. it will handle all for you.. might be easier solution but you need to learn a new tech.. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. The best practice is to make small API calls for each component.

You should load each screen with a loading, then call the API in
componentDidMount after receiving the response shows the data.

2. For this kind of action, first, make the API call, make the like button disable, update the store after successful API call.

Disable the button because of some user double-tap. This kink of APIs is usually fast, so loading does not have a good UX. The loading will be removed before full animation. Always update store data on the response, not the request because you need to revert the store changes if the API calls failed.

Comment: What if the internet is too slow ? That's where my concerns are as for just giving a like they got to wait for 2-3 sec. Let's say on EDGE connectivity..

Comment: They will see a disable button for the time. As the user knows about the internet status, he will expect that. The number of user with a bad internet connection is much lower of user with good internet speed. Therefore, create the UX for regular users.